# Effective and simple way of storing multiline strings of text?

Tags: c++, text

I'm trying to find a way to do this.

My game is multilingual. 
I have English.txt, French.txt, etc..

I'm wondering what would be a good way to store it in the file for example:

```
<sendbutton.tooltip>
Use this button to send text.

The text can be as long as you like!
</sendbutton.tooltip>
```

or

```
sendbutton.tooltip = Use this button to send text.\n\nThe text can be as long as you like!
```

I then will map these strings to their element name for runtime use.

Other than using a standard like XML, what is usually done to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this kind of localization tasks is done with [GNU gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/gettext.html).

Answer (score 1):

It depends when are you going to load the file.

For standard translation stuff, I recommend you take a look at gettext. It provides translation tools and easy way to include it. You can store English text a C strings enclosed with translation macro *() or T*() or whatever, and gettext would provide you with strings that need translating. It also tracks the translations that need to be updated when original English text changes. You store all translations for specific language in separate files.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for C++ but maybe resource files where you create a separate file for each language and have key/value pairs for the lookup with each langauge using the same key but message text is in the correct language e.g.

```
resources.de
  LOGOUT, Abmelden

resources.en
  LOGOUT, Logout
```

then depending on users language choice, you load the appropriate resource file to display the correct text.  Think you would just store the mutlilines with /n as in your second example.